# converting shp to fileGDB with ogr2ogr changes geometry type?

Tags: shapefile, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, geometry-conversion

I'm converting a shapefile to file geodatabase with GDAL 1.11.3 and the ESRI FileGDB driver.

ogrinfo on the .shp gives:

```
$ ogrinfo NED1_Index.shp
INFO: Open of `NED1_Index.shp'
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: NED1_Index (Polygon)
```

I run this command:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" nedtest.gdb NED1_Index.shp
```

or this one specifying the geometry type:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" -nlt POLYGON nedtest.gdb NED1_Index.shp
```

and then ogrinfo on the output fileGDB gives:

```
$ ogrinfo nedtest.gdb/  
INFO: Open of `nedtest.gdb/'  
  using driver `FileGDB' successful.  
1: NED1_Index (Multi Polygon)
```

Why is the geometry changing to MultiPolygon?

Comment: Neither shapefile nor file geodatabase make a distinction between polygon or multipolygon, so this is likely just an artifact of driver implementation.