# Can't set OGR layer geometry type in Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I'm trying to create a layer of geometry type polygon, with a feature of geometry type polygon, and a geometry of type polygon. However, no matter how I attempt to set the geom type of the feature, geometry, or layer, the layer is always set to multipolygon.

Here is some example code to show what I mean:

```
# Create test polygon
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(1179091.1646903288, 712782.8838459781)
ring.AddPoint(1161053.0218226474, 667456.2684348812)
ring.AddPoint(1214704.933941905, 641092.8288590391)
ring.AddPoint(1228580.428455506, 682719.3123998424)
ring.AddPoint(1218405.0658121984, 721108.1805541387)
ring.AddPoint(1179091.1646903288, 712782.8838459781)
geom = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
geom.AddGeometry(ring)

print(geom.GetGeometryName()) # returns POLYGON

# Open the FGDB
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("FileGDB")
path = "/path/to/polygon.gdb"
if not os.path.exists(path):
    data_source = driver.CreateDataSource(path)
else:
    data_source = driver.Open(path, 1)

# Define the spatial reference to use
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# Create the layer
layer_name = "polygon".encode("utf-8")
layer = data_source.CreateLayer(layer_name, srs, ogr.wkbPolygon)

print(ogr.GeometryTypeToName(layer.GetGeomType())) # returns Multi Polygon

# Create the feature
feat_def = ogr.FeatureDefn()
feat_def.SetGeomType(ogr.wkbPolygon)
feature = ogr.Feature(feat_def)

print(ogr.GeometryTypeToName(feature.GetDefnRef().GetGeomType())) # returns Polygon

# Set the geometry
feature.SetGeometry(geom)

print(feature.GetGeometryRef().GetGeometryName()) # returns POLYGON

# Create the feature in the layer
layer.CreateFeature(feature)

# Dereference the feature
feature = None

# Save and close the data source
data_source = None
```

- The first print, I show that the geometry I created is of type
  polygon
- The second print, I show that the layer's geometry type is of
  multipolygon, despite me initializing the layer with type polygon.
- The third print shows that I did set the feature's geometry type to
  polygon when explicitly creating a `FeatureDefn`
- The fourth print shows that after setting the feature's geometry, it
  is still type polygon

Here's the output of `ogrinfo`:

```
$ ogrinfo polygon.gdb/ polygon
INFO: Open of `polygon.gdb/'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.

Layer name: polygon
Geometry: Multi Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (1161053.021823, 641092.828859) - (1228580.428456, 721108.180554)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
FID Column = OBJECTID
Geometry Column = SHAPE
OGRFeature(polygon):1
  MULTIPOLYGON Z (((1179091.16469033 712782.883845978 0,1218405.0658122 721108.180554139 0,1228580.42845551 682719.312399842 0,1214704.93394191 641092.828859039 0,1161053.02182265 667456.268434881 0,1179091.16469033 712782.883845978 0)))
```

I've looked everywhere in the (somewhat useless) OGR Python bindings API and have found nothing useful. So, how do I actually set the layer to be of geometry type polygon?

This is with Python 2.7.15 and GDAL 2.3.2 on CentOS 7.5.

Comment: Does FileGDB support Polygon and Multipolygon geometries as different things? Have you got a FileGDB somewhere that presents as "Polygon" and not "Multipolygon"? I can't find anything in the driver docs. And I don't have write-capability for FileGDB on Linux....

Comment: Ahaha. Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173585/converting-shp-to-filegdb-with-ogr2ogr-changes-geometry-type

Comment: Ha, I see. What's funny is just as I was checking back on this question I was thinking "I wonder if FGDBs even support polygon vs multipolygon" because I had read about how shapefiles don't differentiate. Thanks for pointing it out to me